# Estou tendo um erro nullpointer e não sei como fixar

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

O codigo que eu estou usando é este:

```
public ForumGroups getMainGroup() {
        if (Constants.SQL_ENABLED) {
            int lowest = -1;
            ForumGroups g = null;
            for (ForumGroup group : forumGroups) {
                if (group.getGroup().ordinal() < lowest || g == null) {
                    lowest = group.getGroup().ordinal();
                    g = group.getGroup();
                }
            }
            if (g == null)
                return ForumGroups.MEMBER;
            else
                return g;
        }
        return ForumGroups.OWNER;
    }
```

E estou obtendo erro nesta linha

```
if (group.getGroup().ordinal() < lowest || g == null) {
```

O que faço?

erro aqui:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ophion.rs.game.player.Player.getMainGroup(Player.java:4118)
    at ophion.rs.game.player.Player.InterfaceManager$3.run(InterfaceManager.java:472)
    at ophion.rs.game.tasks.WorldTasksManager.processTasks(WorldTasksManager.java:18)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poste o stacktrace do erro para ficar mais fácil de ajudar...

Comment: Que objeto é o `group`? Sem outras partes relevantes fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: assim não... poste na sua pergunta o stacktrace

Comment: Sou novo nisso aqui kk desculpa

Comment: Rode um debug ai provavelmente o método group.getGroup().ordinal() está retornando um NULL. Debugando e verificando o objeto group, talvez você consiga detectar o erro.

Comment: Rodei mas não to conseguindo detectar, o que faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` acontece quando você tenta acessar um membro(variável ou método) de um **objeto que está com a referência nula**.

No seu código `if (group.getGroup().ordinal() < lowest || g == null) {`, 2 objetos podem estar nulos: `group` ou `group.getGroup()`.

Assim, a exceção ocorre ou quando ele tenta executar o método `group.getGroup()` ou `group.getGroup().ordinal()`.

Sendo assim, você precisa verificar se esses valores estão nulos antes de verificar o método `group.getGroup().ordinal()`, ficando assim:

```
if( (null != group && null != group.getGroup() && group.getGroup.ordinal() < lowest) || g == null)
```

Veja que o if ficou muito extenso e isso pode ser de difícil entendimento. Assim você pode criar um método para as verificações de null:

```
private boolean isGroupNull(Group g){
  return null != g && null != g.getGroup();
}
```

e utilizar isso no seu if anterior:

```
if ( (!isGroupNull(group) && group.getGroup.ordinal() < lowest) || g == null)
```

Observe que tivemos que colocar um parêntese a mais, pois anteriormente verificavamos `A || B`.. agora estamos verificando `(C && A) || B`

**UPDATE:**

Dentro do if você tenta fazer 2 atribuições que dependem da mesma verificação que fizemos para ver se os objetos estão nulos. Se eles estiverem nulos dará erro de novo, conforme você relatou.

Então vamos mudar a lógica do if:

```
for (ForumGroup group : forumGroups) {
  if(!isGroupNull(group)){
    if (group.getGroup().ordinal() < lowest || g == null) {
      lowest = group.getGroup().ordinal();
      g = group.getGroup();
    }
  }
}
```

Assim você "aproveita" a verificação que fizemos para as 2 situações.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma, agora o erro tornou à esta linha:

lowest = group.getGroup().ordinal();

EDIT:
Em seguida eu comentei esta linha e o código rodou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado galera vocês são incríveis!

Comment: vou editar a resposta

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Pedro, muito obrigado pela explicação completa e pelo funcionamento do que eu necessitava. Como dá pontos ás pessoas ? :)

Comment: Clique na setinha para cima ao lado da minha resposta... E, se você tiver permissão já, clique no checkzinho embaixo para indicar a resposta correta. Aproveite e faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site para aprender essas coisas.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa desmembrar esse if em pedaços, ou seja:

```
if( (group.getGroup() != null && group.getGroup().ordinal() < lowest) || g == null )
```

O que provavelmente está ocorrendo é que o getGroup() está retornando null (lei de Demeter).